# How do I import a project into android studio that is actually a github repository that I have already cloned to my computer?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I forked a public repository on github and cloned it to a directory on my computer. I have also set up the remote upstream to sync the project. But now, how should I import the project in android studio so that any changes I make can be updated directly through android studio? I read about the create new project, then check out project from version control (which has two options git and github, which I did not understand) answer. I can also simply import the project from the local directory into android studio, but then how do I set it up to make changes and commit to actual repository on github?

Comment: I did all of this through git bash, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

- I would suggest not to make your android project always save changes
  on github too because sometimes, what happens is that just for your
  understanding, you make a java class or any xml file but then it
  would also get saved in your github account which you don't want.
- So, I would say that import your project normally and commit changes
  to your github repository time to time manually by using the
  following steps :-

  1. `git status` - to check what files you changed in your project
  2. `git add your_modified_file` - to add the modified file
  3. `git commit -a -m "your_message"` - to commit your changes with a
     proper message describing your changes.
  4. `git push origin master` - To push your changes onto your repository 
     at github account. We usually do origin master because we are not 
     changing our branch.

Comment: I think, in #3 `-a` flag is not needed since #2 `added` all files already.

Comment: so there is no way to select which files to commit from inside android studio?

Comment: @sajibkhan that -a signifies append. It means that whatever msg we are passing will show only on the file we changed not everywhere.
Thanks !!

Comment: @Tikli , When you'll write `git status`, it will show files that you changed in your project with red colour, so that, you can identify them. And, then according to your wish add them one by one by specifying their fileName.
Thanks !!